# boxplot() being tripped up by set_yticks() format

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, formatting, subplot

I am trying to make two boxplots on one figure, using `plt.subplots()`. I have successfully done this multiple times, making the following the result:
[image: Produced Without <code>set_yticks</code> formatting]

I had messed around with the scale and because I am plotting multiple sets of data that range from 0.0001 to 100, depending on the dataframes being looped through the graphing process, I need to have a scale that is either in scientific format for easy readability or in floats with a precision of about two digits past the decimal. To solve this, I produced the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mindex=pd.date_range('07/01/2012', periods=96, freq='H')
data00=np.random.rand(96)*20
data01=np.random.rand(96)*0.01
data10=np.random.rand(96)*20
data11=np.random.rand(96)*0.01
df00=pd.DataFrame({'Observed': data00},index=mindex)
df01=pd.DataFrame({'Observed': data01},index=mindex)
df10=pd.DataFrame({'WRF': data10},index=mindex)
df11=pd.DataFrame({'WRF': data11},index=mindex)
df0list=[df00,df01]
df1list=[df10,df11]
for k in xrange(len(df0list)):
    #Graphing
    df0list[k]['Hour']=pd.Series(df0list[k].index.hour,index=df0list[k].index)
    df1list[k]['Hour']=pd.Series(df1list[k].index.hour,index=df1list[k].index)
    if df0list[k]['Observed'].max() >= df1list[k]['WRF'].max():
        ymax=df0list[k]['Observed'].max()
    else:
        ymax=df1list[k]['WRF'].max()
    if df0list[k]['Observed'].min() <= df1list[k]['WRF'].min():
        ymin=df0list[k]['Observed'].min()
    else:
        ymin=df1list[k]['WRF'].min()
    yscale=np.arange(ymin-ymin*0.1,ymax+ymax*0.005,((ymax+ymax*0.005)-(ymin-ymin*0.1))/10.)
    if ymin > 0.01:
        ybounds=['{:.2f}'.format(i) for i in yscale]
    else:
        ybounds=['{:.2e}'.format(i) for i in yscale]
    fig,axes=plt.subplots(ncols=1,nrows=2, figsize=(28,20))
    df0list[k].boxplot(ax=axes[0],by='Hour', whis= [10, 90], sym='')
    axes[0].set_yticks(ybounds)
    df1list[k].boxplot(ax=axes[1],by='Hour', whis= [.10, .90], sym='')
    axes[1].set_yticks(ybounds)
    plt.show()
```

This produced graphs that only display the top graph with bounds that are not properly fitting. I am not sure how matplotlib handles displaying formats and thought that by making the `set_yticks()` function take in a pre-formatted numpy array it would display in whatever that array is formatted. However, now the graph will not even save giving me `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`. Do I need to format this differently?

Comment: this surely isn't a minimal example of the problem -- can you set up a sample that includes its own dummy data and doesn't have anything not relevant to the problem? E.g., probably no "set title" lines, but in general nothing that doesn't make a difference to the final difference.

Comment: My apologies. I have edited out all that persisted from my own code that was not necessary.

Comment: Fix the TypeError; it isn't a complete or verifiable example until it shows the behavior you want to fix, and only that behavior.  Re the original problem:  you probably want `set_ylim` instead of `set_yticks`.